# How write the values from the database into an array in Flash Builder 4

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I want to display multiple images and when rollover above it i must get a tooltips (names). The same names are in the database mySQL. Naturally, to tooltips displayed without delay, preferably immediately put all the names from the database into an array and then manipulate them. Tell me please what I do wrong?

Php class to connect database:

```
public function getDataMean($id,$dir_id) {
    $mysql = mysql_connect(DATABASE_SERVER, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
     mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';");
     mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';");
    mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);
    $query = "SELECT name FROM files WHERE id='".$id."' AND dir_id='".$dir_id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    return $result;
}
```

FB4 code:

```
        public var Names:Array = new Array();
        public var textName:String;

        protected function decks_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            arrayOfNumber = new Array();
            generateArray(minCount,maxCount);       
            randomize(arrayOfNumber);
            var dir_id:int = 7;

            card1.source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+String(arrayOfNumber[0])+".jpg";
            card2.source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+String(arrayOfNumber[1])+".jpg";
            card3.source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+String(arrayOfNumber[2])+".jpg";
            for (var i:int=0; i<4; i++){
                getDataMeanResult.token = authors.getDataMean(arrayOfNumber[i], dir_id);
                Names[i] = getDataMeanResult.lastResult[0].name;
            }   
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Comment: Error in this line: 
Names [i] = getDataMeanResult.lastResult [0]. Name;

I use a standard function FB4 data connections PHP. If i use only one value - everything works fine. The problem of transferring data in the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to see from your code. But as I understood; you have some cards with in ID each, and you want to grab matching data from array when ever the user interacts with that card? - Correct?

If that is the case you properly want to use an associative array instead. In AS3 you use an instance of the Oject class as an associative array (yes that does seem a bit wierd). So maybe you should rewrite your code declaring Names as a Object instead of Array.

With that being said I can see one other problem with your code, you write `Names[i] = ...`, but you have not declared the size of the Array (or maybe that is what the `generateArray` function does?). Try using `Names.push(getDataMeanResult.lastResult[0].name)` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much Lillemanden.

Yes, you are absolutely right. I have a few cards (images) and each card has its own name. All of these names are in the mySQL database. I want to rollover on the cards appeared tooltips. But if a lot of cards, it may appear a delay in the appearance of tooltips. So I decided to enter the data from the database into an array and then when you over pics to show them (while I was testing a data output by clicking to images).

Comment: <mx:Image x="125" y="262" source="card/1.jpg" width="98" height="165" id="card1"  mouseOver="imageOver(1)" click="getN(0)"/>
 <mx:Image x="247" y="262" source="card/1.jpg" width="98" height="165" id="card2"  mouseOver="imageOver(2)" click="getN(1)"/>
 <mx:Image x="379" y="262" source="card/1.jpg" width="98" height="165" id="card3"   mouseOver="imageOver(3)" click="getN(2)"/>

   protected function getN(s:uint):void {
    nameText.text = nameArray[s];
   }

Comment: By the way, do not tell my way to use variables instead of an id picture? It is necessary to organize a cycle. Instead:

card1.source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+String(arrayOfNumber[0])+".jpg";
card2.source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+String(arrayOfNumber[1])+".jpg";
card3.source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+String(arrayOfNumber[2])+".jpg";

 
do like this: 
for (var s:uint=0; s<3; s++){
cardId[s].source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+String(arrayOfNumber[s])+".jpg"
}

Comment: >In AS3 you use an instance of the Oject class as an associative array (yes that does seem a bit wierd). So maybe you should rewrite your code declaring Names as a Object instead of Array.

Oh, it's too complicated for me. There were no available articles / instructions on this subject? 

>Try using Names.push(getDataMeanResult.lastResult[0].name) instead.
Unfortunately your way does not fit. I get an error when testing in this line. TypeError: Error # 1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Comment: Then this simple question: how i can pass a data from the mySQL database into a variable using the wizards FB4 (connect with PHP)?
If you can show examples please.I could not find examples. Send data to DataGrid or text field - much, but not to variable.
Sorry that i have not formatting the text and no highlighting code - is an inconvenience of the service:)